# Complex Sum Type in Scala

Tags: scala, types, algebraic-data-types

I have the following Type that i need to model:

```
sealed trait FieldType

case object INT extends FieldType
case object UINT extends FieldType
case object FLOAT extends FieldType
case object DOUBLE extends FieldType
case object BOOL extends FieldType
case object STRING extends FieldType
case object DATETIME extends FieldType

case class LIST(fieldType: FieldType) extends FieldType
case class SET(fieldType: FieldType)  extends FieldType
```

The Issue i have is that in fact `LIST` and `SET` are actually `ComplexFieldType` that contain FieldType. **In other words LIST Can Not Contain List or SET, same thing for SET.**

What would be the proper way to model that, to ensure exhaustivity issue i.e. having the compiler telling me when i am missing some values.

I tried to introduce intermediary sealed trait as in `SimpleFieldType` and `ComplexFieldType` but then the pattern matching was messed up.

Only solution that i see if I don't want to compound things as in

```
case object LIST_INT
```

is to use smart constructor for `LIST` and `SET`.

However I thought drop a note and see what the scalaSphere knows about it.

Comment: The intermediate trait is the appropriate solution, yo do not need to match the intermediate traits just the final values.

Comment: Why not using TypeTag provided by Scala?

Comment: @texasbruce This adds dependency on `scala-reflect`, runtime reflection is comparatively slow, and there are [bugs](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Areflection) in reflection in 2.x, which are not being actively fixed.

Answer (score 3):

It works indeed as such:

```
sealed trait FieldType

sealed trait SimpleFieldType extends FieldType
case object INT extends SimpleFieldType
case object UINT extends SimpleFieldType
case object FLOAT extends SimpleFieldType
case object DOUBLE extends SimpleFieldType
case object BOOL extends SimpleFieldType
case object STRING extends SimpleFieldType
case object DATETIME extends SimpleFieldType
sealed trait ComplexFieldType extends FieldType
case class LIST(fieldType: SimpleFieldType) extends ComplexFieldType
case class SET(fieldType: SimpleFieldType)  extends ComplexFieldType
```

```
val field1: FieldType = INT

field1 match {
    case FLOAT =>
    case BOOL =>
    case INT =>
    case UINT =>
    case DATETIME =>
    case DOUBLE =>
    case STRING =>
    case LIST(_) =>
    case SET(_) =>
}
```

ScalaC detect the non-exhaustiveness. I just had to use https://github.com/rtimush/sbt-rewarn#sbt-rewarn as the recompilation just skip it